# Using INDIRECT and IF functions together with dynamic range

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, worksheet-function, excel-indirect

I'm trying to combine the INDIRECT and IF functions together so I can drag formulas down without getting a #REF! error when I run my macro. Currently, I have one sheet that has all the IF functions and another sheet that it refers to. The current IF function is:

```
=IF('First Half'!T2="Loblaws","CA",IF(RIGHT('First Half'!T2,6)="Canada","CA","US"))
```

`First Half` is the sheet and `T2` is the referenced cell. I want to be able to use INDIRECT so if the reference row `2` gets deleted, I won't get a #REF! error. But I also want the formula to be dragged down to reference `T3` on the next row.

Comment: Sorry, same sheet, just a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try (in Row2 or apply an offset to each `ROW()`):

```
=IF(INDIRECT("'First Half'!T"&ROW())="Loblaws","CA",IF(RIGHT(INDIRECT("'First Half'!T"&ROW()),6)="Canada","CA","US"))
```